# Nginx FCGI setup with regexp-based host

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to build a deploy server that would have wildcard host serving several directories (let's say i'm previewing master and dev branches of some project), but i keep failing to pass computed document root to fcgi. The MCVE example to describe would be this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ~(\w+).tld;
        root /srv/www/$1;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

If i try to get something like `alpha.tld/index.txt`, nginx correctly serves me that file, computing `$document_root` as `/srv/www/alpha`. However, as soon as i try to invoke FCGI, magic is gone:

```
2017/03/28 14:33:18 [debug] 1761#1761: *8 open index "/srv/www/beta/index.php"
2017/03/28 14:33:18 [debug] 1761#1761: *8 internal redirect: "/index.php?"
// nginx has found the file, that's great
...
2017/03/28 14:33:18 [debug] 1761#1761: *8 http script copy: "/srv/www/"
2017/03/28 14:33:18 [debug] 1761#1761: *8 http script capture: ""
2017/03/28 14:33:18 [debug] 1761#1761: *8 http script var: "/index.php"
2017/03/28 14:33:18 [debug] 1761#1761: *8 trying to use file: "/index.php" "/srv/www//index.php"
// but it has failed to pass captured regex match down to fcgi
```

I have failed to find anything using google and requests like 'nginx fcgi regex', and manually setting FCGI params doesn't help. Is there any solution for this?

p.s. the real setup is rather more complex than example, and i can't create nginx configurations for all possible hosts in advance, so i can't really use anything but regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this suddenly works:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        // nothing has changed but regexp group naming and referencing
        server_name ~(?<subdomain>\w+).tld;
        root /srv/www/$subdomain;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
               // even $document_root seems to be computed as expected
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

I'm not sure this is correct approach - i do understand that this is tightly coupled to variable resolution order and may fail at any nginx update, so any better answers are appreciated.